# Azure required packages installation using "yum"

Tags: linux, azure, azure-activedirectory, linux-on-azure

I've been trying to set up azure domain services and a virtual machine to work together, I'm close to the end of the process but I got stuck in a rut. According to the documentation, I should execute this command to install the required packages on the linux virtual machine :

`sudo yum install realmd sssd krb5-workstation krb5-libs samba-common-tools`.

This is the error I get every time :

`There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>`

I've read a couple of posts on the internet and it appears that "yum" is not the best way to install packages, the question is then, how do I install those packages without yum?

**Ubuntu VM**

Comment: Ubuntu indeed, sorry for not providing that information

Comment: yeah that's what I found, but what will the command look like then? Do I just change yum install to apt-get install? Like so : sudo apt-get install realmd sssd krb5-workstation krb5-libs samba-common-tools

Comment: so the package names don't need to be changed when I replace yum with apt-get, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95519/discussion-between-peter-utekal-and-lx07).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Microsoft documentation, for Ubuntu you need :

`sudo apt-get install krb5-user samba sssd sssd-tools libnss-sss libpam-sss ntp ntpdate realmd adcli`

See [Join an Ubuntu virtual machine in Azure to a managed domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-ubuntu-linux-vm)